How to log a hostname of requests to firebase hosted API, when custom domain is used and Express
I have API build as Firebase cloud function, running express webserver and the function is connected to custom domain. I want to log the url clients are using to initiate request to the API.
Reading the headers of the request - the hostname is the url of the cloud function and the x-forwarded-host is the custom domain.
The function looks like:
const app = express();

app.use(cors);
app.use(debug);

app.get('/api/endpoint1', authenticate, endpoint1Handler);
app.post('/api/endpoint2', authenticate, validateParams([...]), endpoint2Handler);
app.get('/api/doc', (req, res) => res.send(docHtml));

export default region(...).runWith(...).https.onRequest(app);


What do you mean by "hostname of incoming requests"? What exactly did you try that didn't work the way you expect?  Please edit the question to give a more clear example of what you're expecting to receive.  Also please try logging all of the request HTTP headers to see if what you want might be in there somewhere.

I'm not sure what issue you have. Log each of the received HTTP headers to see if the information you need is there.
